# Need an alternative word for drop-off point

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Can someone give me an alternative word for drop-off point? The way we use this word is to drop and pick up materials in an area.

What we do is we transport materials from one area to another area by material movement request. We don't store anything. We have a term "staging area" for the receiving end. A term we are looking for is for the final delivery area. Because of naming convention we can't use the term "drop point or drop off point". In some case we will pick up a material from final delivery area to staging area by MMR as well.

Comment: I'm tempted to suggest *pick-up point*, but how about *delivery point*?

Comment: I think you need to provide a bit more context. In a warehouse environment this would be the "loading bay", but I don't think the term is general enough.

Comment: What we do is we transport materials from one area to another area by material movement request. We don't store anything. We have a term "staging area" for the receiving end. A term we are looking for is for the final delivery area. Because of naming convention we can't use the term "drop point or drop off point". In some case we will pick up a material from final delivery area to staging area by MMR as well.

Comment: Seems the delivery point suggestion above would work - also if you look to what you wrote yourself:  _from final *delivery area*_ - so it seems applicable.

Comment: Can I use "final destination"?

Comment: Or "deposit location".

Comment: From your description I don't think 'final destination' is correct. A final destination is the customer's address for a delivery or the supplier's premises for a return. I think you mean a place where goods are collected for shipping onward in both directions so that journeys are more efficient than they would otherwise be. I would suggest 'holding point' , 'holding area', 'transfer point', 'collation point' or even 'sorting point' as in 'sorting office'. I think you want to express the idea that multiple items can be left at the location until there are enough for a load to a specific place.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your area is similar to what is referred to in the military as a [distribution point](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/distribution+point). It carries no stock, supplies are obtained from supporting areas and then sent on to their intended destination.

Answer (score 1):

The old-fashioned British English term would be “delivery point”.

An example of this usage is taken from a web [business page](https://www.allbusiness.com/barrons_dictionary/dictionary-delivery-point-bar-code-dpb-4966215-1.html):

> **delivery point bar code (DPB)**
>
> Dictionary of Marketing Terms for: delivery point bar code (DPB)
>
> 11-digit, 62-bar, machine readable bar code representing a nine-digit
> ZIP code plus two additional digits, used to address mail. The actual
> **delivery point** is represented by the last two digits, which indicate
> the last two numbers of a residential address, a P.O. box, rural
> route, or highway contract route.

The reference to a zip code indicates it is also US usage.

This may or may not be appropriate for your circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

The word you're looking for may be **terminus**.

"A final goal: a finishing point".

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/terminus

Comment: A terminus is not specifically a destination though. If I'm on a train that has 6 stops (A,B,C,D,E,F), F would be the terminus, but I might be travelling to _destination D_. The terminus describes the end of the transport line, rather than the end of a shipment (that travels on said transport line).

Answer (score 0):

Though it's frequently used as a nautical term, the word **dock** can be used to refer to any platform where "dropping off" or "picking up" occurs.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dock

> a place (as a wharf or platform) for the loading or unloading of materials

In many warehouses, the area where vehicles are loaded is called the "loading dock."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loading_dock

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking from the perspective of transportation, could you not simply call it the **destination**?

This seems unambiguous, and it encapsulates exactly what you want: the location the shipment needs to be delivered to.